# Codeigniter Auto completion is not working

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

Hello Auto completion is not working well in my application.When we type a name it displays only a blank list[ Screenshots attached ].

Controller Code

```
    public function list_UserByName($letters)
{
    if(strpos($letters, ","))
    {
        $letters1 = explode(",",$letters);
        $lecount  = count($letters1);
        $letters  = $letters1[$lecount-1];
    }
    $letters = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9 ]/si","",$letters);
    $response=$this->user_model->getAutoUserList($letters);
}
```

Model Code

```
public function getAutoUserList($letters)
{
    $letters = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9 ]/si","",$letters);
    //AND user_type='C' AND user_status='A'
    $query="select * from gm_users where uname Like '%$letters%'";
    $result_query    =$this->db->query($query);
    foreach($result_query->result() as $result)
    {
    //echo "###".$result."|";
    //$pinlevel =$this->functions->get_pinlevel($result->pinLevel);
    //echo $result->userId."###".$result->uname." [ ".$pinlevel." ] "."|";
    echo $result->userId."###".$result->uname."".$result->address." ".$result->city."|";
    }

}
```

billing.php

```
   <input type="text" autocomplete="off" size="20" name="txtname" id="txtname" onkeyup="ajax_showOptions(this,'getCountriesByLetters',event);" value=""/>
```

ajax-dynamic-list.js

```
    /************************************************************************************************************
(C) www.dhtmlgoodies.com, April 2006

This is a script from www.dhtmlgoodies.com. You will find this and a lot of other scripts at our website.   

Terms of use:
You are free to use this script as long as the copyright message is kept intact. However, you may not
redistribute, sell or repost it without our permission.

Thank you!

www.dhtmlgoodies.com
Alf Magne Kalleland

************************************************************************************************************/   

var ajaxBox_offsetX = 25;
var ajaxBox_offsetY = 5;
var ajax_list_externalFile = site_url+'/catalog/list_UserByName';   // Path to external file
var minimumLettersBeforeLookup = 1; // Number of letters entered before a lookup is performed.

var ajax_list_objects = new Array();
var ajax_list_cachedLists = new Array();
var ajax_list_activeInput = false;
var ajax_list_activeItem;
var ajax_list_optionDivFirstItem = false;
var ajax_list_currentLetters = new Array();
var ajax_optionDiv = false;
var ajax_optionDiv_iframe = false;

var ajax_list_MSIE = false;
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE')>=0 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Opera')<0)ajax_list_MSIE=true;

var currentListIndex = 0;

function ajax_getTopPos(inputObj)
{

  var returnValue = inputObj.offsetTop;
  while((inputObj = inputObj.offsetParent) != null){
    returnValue += inputObj.offsetTop;
  }
  return returnValue;
}
function ajax_list_cancelEvent()
{
    return false;
}

function ajax_getLeftPos(inputObj)
{
  var returnValue = inputObj.offsetLeft;
  while((inputObj = inputObj.offsetParent) != null)returnValue += inputObj.offsetLeft;

  return returnValue;
}

// Edited
function ajax_option_setValue_bkp(e,inputObj)
{
    if(!inputObj)inputObj=this;
    var tmpValue = inputObj.innerHTML;
    //alert(inputObj.id);
    document.getElementById('saleUserId').value=inputObj.id;
    if(ajax_list_MSIE)tmpValue = inputObj.innerText;else tmpValue = inputObj.textContent;
    if(!tmpValue)tmpValue = inputObj.innerHTML;
    val  = ajax_list_activeInput.value.split(',');
    vals = '';
    count = val.length - 1;
    for(i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        vals = vals + val[i] + ',';
    }

    ajax_list_activeInput.value = vals + tmpValue;
    if(document.getElementById(ajax_list_activeInput.name + '_hidden'))document.getElementById(ajax_list_activeInput.name + '_hidden').value = inputObj.id; 
    ajax_options_hide();
}

function ajax_option_setValue(e,inputObj)
{
    if(!inputObj)inputObj=this;
    var tmpValue = inputObj.innerHTML;
    //alert(inputObj.id);
    document.getElementById('saleUserId').value=inputObj.id;
    if(ajax_list_MSIE)tmpValue = inputObj.innerText;else tmpValue = inputObj.textContent;
    if(!tmpValue)tmpValue = inputObj.innerHTML;
    ajax_list_activeInput.value = tmpValue;
    if(document.getElementById(ajax_list_activeInput.name + '_hidden'))document.getElementById(ajax_list_activeInput.name + '_hidden').value = inputObj.id; 
    ajax_options_hide();
}

function ajax_options_hide()
{
    if(ajax_optionDiv)ajax_optionDiv.style.display='none';  
    if(ajax_optionDiv_iframe)ajax_optionDiv_iframe.style.display='none';
}

function ajax_options_rollOverActiveItem(item,fromKeyBoard)
{
    if(ajax_list_activeItem)ajax_list_activeItem.className='optionDiv';
    item.className='optionDivSelected';
    ajax_list_activeItem = item;

    if(fromKeyBoard){
        if(ajax_list_activeItem.offsetTop>ajax_optionDiv.offsetHeight){
            ajax_optionDiv.scrollTop = ajax_list_activeItem.offsetTop - ajax_optionDiv.offsetHeight + ajax_list_activeItem.offsetHeight + 2 ;
        }
        if(ajax_list_activeItem.offsetTop<ajax_optionDiv.scrollTop)
        {
            ajax_optionDiv.scrollTop = 0;   
        }
    }
}

function ajax_option_list_buildList(letters,paramToExternalFile)
{

    ajax_optionDiv.innerHTML = '';
    ajax_list_activeItem = false;
    if(ajax_list_cachedLists[paramToExternalFile][letters.toLowerCase()].length<=1){
        ajax_options_hide();
        return;         
    }



    ajax_list_optionDivFirstItem = false;
    var optionsAdded = false;
    for(var no=0;no<ajax_list_cachedLists[paramToExternalFile][letters.toLowerCase()].length;no++){
        if(ajax_list_cachedLists[paramToExternalFile][letters.toLowerCase()][no].length==0)continue;
        optionsAdded = true;
        var div = document.createElement('DIV');
        var items = ajax_list_cachedLists[paramToExternalFile][letters.toLowerCase()][no].split(/###/gi);

        if(ajax_list_cachedLists[paramToExternalFile][letters.toLowerCase()].length==1 && ajax_list_activeInput.value == items[0]){
            ajax_options_hide();
            return;                     
        }


        div.innerHTML = items[items.length-1];
        div.id = items[0];
     div.className='optionDiv';
        div.onmouseover = function(){ ajax_options_rollOverActiveItem(this,false) }
        div.onclick = ajax_option_setValue;
        if(!ajax_list_optionDivFirstItem)ajax_list_optionDivFirstItem = div;
        ajax_optionDiv.appendChild(div);
    }   
    if(optionsAdded){
        ajax_optionDiv.style.display='block';
        if(ajax_optionDiv_iframe)ajax_optionDiv_iframe.style.display='';
        ajax_options_rollOverActiveItem(ajax_list_optionDivFirstItem,true);
    }

}

function ajax_option_list_showContent(ajaxIndex,inputObj,paramToExternalFile,whichIndex)
{
    if(whichIndex!=currentListIndex)return;
    var letters = inputObj.value;
    var content = ajax_list_objects[ajaxIndex].response;
    var elements = content.split('|');
    //alert(content);
    ajax_list_cachedLists[paramToExternalFile][letters.toLowerCase()] = elements;
    ajax_option_list_buildList(letters,paramToExternalFile);

}

function ajax_option_resize(inputObj)
{
    ajax_optionDiv.style.top = (ajax_getTopPos(inputObj) + inputObj.offsetHeight + ajaxBox_offsetY) + 'px';
    ajax_optionDiv.style.left = (ajax_getLeftPos(inputObj) + ajaxBox_offsetX) + 'px';
    if(ajax_optionDiv_iframe){
        ajax_optionDiv_iframe.style.left = ajax_optionDiv.style.left;
        ajax_optionDiv_iframe.style.top = ajax_optionDiv.style.top;         
    }       

}

function ajax_showOptions(inputObj,paramToExternalFile,e)
{
        document.getElementById('saleUserId').value='';
    if(e.keyCode==13 || e.keyCode==9)return;
    if(ajax_list_currentLetters[inputObj.name]==inputObj.value)return;
    if(!ajax_list_cachedLists[paramToExternalFile])ajax_list_cachedLists[paramToExternalFile] = new Array();
    ajax_list_currentLetters[inputObj.name] = inputObj.value;
    if(!ajax_optionDiv){
        ajax_optionDiv = document.createElement('DIV');
        ajax_optionDiv.id = 'ajax_listOfOptions';   
        document.body.appendChild(ajax_optionDiv);

        if(ajax_list_MSIE){
            ajax_optionDiv_iframe = document.createElement('IFRAME');
            ajax_optionDiv_iframe.border='0';
            ajax_optionDiv_iframe.style.width =   ajax_optionDiv.clientWidth + 'px';
            ajax_optionDiv_iframe.style.height = ajax_optionDiv.clientHeight + 'px';
            ajax_optionDiv_iframe.id = 'ajax_listOfOptions_iframe';

            document.body.appendChild(ajax_optionDiv_iframe);
        }

        var allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
        for(var no=0;no<allInputs.length;no++){
            if(!allInputs[no].onkeyup)allInputs[no].onfocus = ajax_options_hide;
        }           
        var allSelects = document.getElementsByTagName('SELECT');
        for(var no=0;no<allSelects.length;no++){
            allSelects[no].onfocus = ajax_options_hide;
        }

        var oldonkeydown=document.body.onkeydown;
        if(typeof oldonkeydown!='function'){
            document.body.onkeydown=ajax_option_keyNavigation;
        }else{
            document.body.onkeydown=function(){
                oldonkeydown();
            ajax_option_keyNavigation() ;}
        }
        var oldonresize=document.body.onresize;
        if(typeof oldonresize!='function'){
            document.body.onresize=function()  {ajax_option_resize(inputObj); };
        }else{
            document.body.onresize=function(){oldonresize();
            ajax_option_resize(inputObj) ;}
        }

    }

    if(inputObj.value.length<minimumLettersBeforeLookup){
        ajax_options_hide();
        return;
    }


    ajax_optionDiv.style.top = (ajax_getTopPos(inputObj) + inputObj.offsetHeight  + ajaxBox_offsetY) + 'px';
    ajax_optionDiv.style.left = (ajax_getLeftPos(inputObj) + ajaxBox_offsetX) + 'px';
    if(ajax_optionDiv_iframe){
        ajax_optionDiv_iframe.style.left = ajax_optionDiv.style.left;
        ajax_optionDiv_iframe.style.top = ajax_optionDiv.style.top;         
    }

    ajax_list_activeInput = inputObj;
    ajax_optionDiv.onselectstart =  ajax_list_cancelEvent;
    currentListIndex++;
    if(ajax_list_cachedLists[paramToExternalFile][inputObj.value.toLowerCase()]){
        ajax_option_list_buildList(inputObj.value,paramToExternalFile,currentListIndex);            
    }else{
        var tmpIndex=currentListIndex/1;
        ajax_optionDiv.innerHTML = '';
        var ajaxIndex = ajax_list_objects.length;

    ajax_list_objects[ajaxIndex] = new sack();

        var search_key = inputObj.value.replace(" ","+");
        //search_key1 = search_key.replace(",",",");
        var url = ajax_list_externalFile + '/' +search_key;


        ajax_list_objects[ajaxIndex].requestFile = url; // Specifying which file to get
        ajax_list_objects[ajaxIndex].onCompletion = function(){ ajax_option_list_showContent(ajaxIndex,inputObj,paramToExternalFile,tmpIndex); };   // Specify function that will be executed after file has been found
        ajax_list_objects[ajaxIndex].runAJAX();     // Execute AJAX function        
    }


}

function wordcount(string) {
  var a = string.split(/\s+/g); // split the sentence into an array of words
  return a.length;
  }
function ajax_option_keyNavigation(e)
{
    if(document.all)e = event;

    if(!ajax_optionDiv)return;
    if(ajax_optionDiv.style.display=='none')return;

    if(e.keyCode==38){  // Up arrow
        if(!ajax_list_activeItem)return;
        if(ajax_list_activeItem && !ajax_list_activeItem.previousSibling)return;
        ajax_options_rollOverActiveItem(ajax_list_activeItem.previousSibling,true);
    }

    if(e.keyCode==40){  // Down arrow
        if(!ajax_list_activeItem){
            ajax_options_rollOverActiveItem(ajax_list_optionDivFirstItem,true);
        }else{
            if(!ajax_list_activeItem.nextSibling)return;
            ajax_options_rollOverActiveItem(ajax_list_activeItem.nextSibling,true);
        }
    }

    /*if(e.keyCode==13 || e.keyCode==9){    // Enter key or tab key
        if(ajax_list_activeItem && ajax_list_activeItem.className=='optionDivSelected')ajax_option_setValue(false,ajax_list_activeItem);
        if(e.keyCode==13)return false; else return true;
    }
    if(e.keyCode==27){  // Escape key
        ajax_options_hide();            
    }*/
}


//document.documentElement.onclick = autoHideList;

function autoHideList(e)
{
    if(document.all)e = event;

    if (e.target) source = e.target;
        else if (e.srcElement) source = e.srcElement;
        if (source.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
            source = source.parentNode;     
    if(source.tagName.toLowerCase()!='input' && source.tagName.toLowerCase()!='textarea')ajax_options_hide();

}
```

Am a beginner in php as well as Codeigniter

Comment: Could you please show you ajax code.

Comment: @phpLearner I have updated my question with ajax code

Comment: @Lighter  am a beginner in php ...echo $result_query; is this correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just echo your data in your controller

change

```
$response=$this->user_model->getAutoUserList($letters);
```

To

```
echo $this->user_model->getAutoUserList($letters);
```

Comment: when you request page using ajax, you need to access to `controller/method`.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
onkeyup="ajax_showOptions(this,'getCountriesByLetters',event);
```

to

```
onkeyup="ajax_showOptions(this,'list_UserByName',event);
```

there is a question on this topic on stackoverflow, but an entire different process.

[My Codeigniter autocomplete with ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794089/my-codeigniter-autocomplete-with-ajax)